# Angular SweetAlert2 Multi Select

Tags: angular, sweetalert2

I need to use `ng-select` directive inside `SweetAlert2`, the following code doesn't work:

```
  const { value: formValues } = await swal.fire({
    title: 'Multiple inputs',
    html:
      '<ng-select id="selectedItems" [items]="'+this._data+'" bindLabel="name"' +
      'placeholder="Items" [multiple]="true">' +
      '</ng-select>',
    focusConfirm: false,
    preConfirm: () => {
      return [
        document.getElementById('parcoursSelected').value
      ]
    }
  })

if (formValues) {
  swal.fire(JSON.stringify(formValues))
}
```

There are two problems:

1. The first one: the input select is not displayed

[image]

2. The second one: I don't know how to get the selected value

[image]

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: is your formValues populated?

Comment: `formValues` is populated by `undefined`, please see the question I added some pictures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know from previous experience using sweet alert and Angular 2+, sweet alert code is injected only on button push, after which it is not recompiled through angular, and therefore you cannot add directives in your swal HTML and expect them to work.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, you're right I cannot use custom directives in sweet alert. So , the solution is to use bootstrap modal.